# option symbol has different em size than other characters

Tags: css

I'm trying to style the `kbd` buttons to have all the same `min-width`, based on the font size of the element.

```
kbd {
  min-width: 1.5em;
}
```

The problem is that it works for all the symbols I've tried, except for `⌃`...

It has a different min-width:

[image: keys]

Why that? How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, figured out that the `min-width` I was setting wasn't enough "large" to make every letter the same width. Increasing it to 1.8 fixed the problem, sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

They're all the same size, the 1.5em that you specified but the caret (ctrl) is a narrower character than the others.  If you set the buttons to have a **width** of 1.5em instead a font-size, that'll make them all the same size.

Give me a shout if this doesn't work and I'll see what I can do to help - might be worth setting up a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about this but what i would suggest is that all the other buttons have the same "character size" or rather the same distance after and before the character and the "^" has another one. This would mean with another font it could also look different again.

Look at following picture:

[image: http://www.designfreebies.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/typeface-similar-width.jpg]

It seems like all the other characters/symbols are like the a and e on this picture, they just have the same width. Your "^" is like the f for example. It's not as wide as the others even if it has the same font-size.

I would suggest you not using width instead of min-width so you can be sure they all have exactly the size you gave them.